# how to make transparent fragment using Compose and Material 3

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, fragment, android-dialogfragment

My application is made of 100% Jetpack Compose (there is no View), I want to make 3 fragments:
Fragment 1 has a UI
fragment 2 is just a custom loader (using animation)
fragment 3 is just a loader (the same one as fragment 2)

my goal is to make the loader appear on top of the first fragments UI, so it will be transparent and just show the loader, (it goes from fragment a ->b (loader) ->c (loader) -> after all the calculations are finished in the fragment 2 and 3 I want to go back to fragment a,
how can I achieve this in fragments 2 and 3, is it possible?

> TL.DR: basically, I want fragments 2 and 3 to have a transparent
> background with blur and show a loader,

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure to be 100% Compose if you still need Fragment? If you are 100% compose you can remove Fragments entirely, replacing them with screen-level composables driven by Navigation Compose.